# Fade Out an Object Once an Other Object has Been Moved in Place with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onkeydown

I am just getting to know jQuery and I got the idea to make a simple Super Mario Imitation. I can move Mario with the arrow keys and I thought I could fade the mushrooms out once Mario is moved in place, but that doesn't seem to work as I expected, if someone could point me to the right direction, I would be very happy!

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Super Mario!</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="mushroom" src="http://ih2.redbubble.net/image.6378228.5104/sticker,375x360.u2.png"/>
        <img class="mario" src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein/mario.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.mushroom {
    position: relative;
    left: 300;
    top: 200;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Keydown function to move mario
    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
        switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
            // Left arrow key pressed
            case 37:
                $('.mario').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
            // Up Arrow Pressed
            case 38:
                $('.mario').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
            // Right Arrow Pressed
            case 39:
                $('.mario').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
            // Down Array Pressed
            case 40:
                $('.mario').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
        }
        // On Mario's arrival remove Mushroom
        $(document).on('keydown', '.mario', function(e){
            var x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft,
                y = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;

            if (x > 300 && x < 400 && y > 200 && y < 300) {
                $('.mushroom').fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

First I tried with an IF statement checking on Mario's css for position - it id not work -, but than I realized, that css is probably not rewritten on keydown. So I am stuck :/

The IF statement idea looked like this:

```
// On Mario's arrival remove Mashroom
$(document).on('keydown', '.mushroom', function() {
    if($('.mario').css("left")=="300" && ("top")=="200") {
        $('.mashroom').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast'); 
    }
});
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Missing

`$('.mario').css("top")`

```
if($('.mario').css("left")=="300" && $('.mario').css("top")=="200") {
//                                   ^              ^
```

Comment: It doesn't work still. I am not sure that the css values of left and top are stored once I move Mario.

Comment: @MiklósDenut Try change event to `keyup`

Comment: This is how that portion of jQuery looks now and still not working:

        `// On Mario's arrival remove Mushroom`
 `$(document).keyup(function(key) {`
        `if($('.mario').css("left")=="300" && $('.mario').css("top")=="200") {`
            `$('.mashroom').remove();` 
        `}`
 `});`

Comment: This is a DEMO of the not functioning app: 

[MarioApp](http://jsfiddle.net/NicolaeDenut/8yF86/)